# Resize an image based on the height of the mobile device

Tags: ios, swift, mobile

How can I resize an image based on the height of the mobile device that's in landscape mode? I have a wide image (a ruler) and want to be able to slide the image back and forth. I've tried scaling the image, but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
func resizeImage(size: CGSize)  {


    let scaleFactor =    imageView.bounds.height / size.height

    let newHeight = imageView.bounds.height * scaleFactor
    let newWidth  = imageView.bounds.width  * scaleFactor

    var newSize: CGSize
    newSize = CGSize(newWidth, newHeight)

    imageView.frame =  CGRect(origin: imageView.frame.origin, size: newSize)

    scrollView.contentSize = imageView.bounds.size
    scrollView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleRightMargin, .flexibleLeftMargin, .flexibleTopMargin, .flexibleRightMargin]
    self.scrollView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit;
}
```

Comment: use autolayout for handling such issue , but you need to manipulate priority of constraint , check once

Answer (score 0):

If you are using storyboard then it is easier to do with auto layout constraints. You have to use `Equal Height Constraint` with the `Multiplier`. Although I am also a beginner and haven't used this method for landscape mode, but I am assuming it ll work for landscape too.

Follow these steps :-

1. Suppose the view you are using in your storyboard while creating the view is of iPhone 7. So your screen height will `667`.
2. Now, suppose in this view your image looks perfect with height `200`.
   So take the the ratio `200/667`=`0.299`
3. Now set `Equal Height Constraint`  by selecting both views (i.e imageView and superView) using the ratio as multiplier.
4. You can check for other devices and orientations with an option on bottom `View as:`

In the end, height constraint of image should look like this. [My height ratio is 0.4 (pic here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsnAB.png)